# YANG: How to specify complex typedefs

Tags: opendaylight, ietf-netmod-yang

I am learning about YANG. I want to a typedef consisting of a Uri and a list of IpAddress.  So I tried something like the following:

```
  typedef mapping {
      type union {

                type inet:uri;

                 list addresses {
                     type inet:IpAddress;
                 }
         }
    }
```

I later want to use this defined type in a container. But the definition above gave me a compilation error. Are YANG typedefs similar to c++ typedefs? How can I define such structures in YANG?

Comment: I'm interested in this as well. I asked a similar [question](https://ask.opendaylight.org/question/27397/defining-an-rpc-method-with-packed-parameters/) some time ago, but never got an answer. Can you try the solution I had found? It didn't work for me, but I suspect I might also have had an other problem.

Answer (score 3):

From what you describe it seems to me like you want to create a reusable definition of a structure that has two fields: a single `uri` and a list of `addresses`. The best tool for this job is [YANG's grouping](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7950#section-7.12). The RFC says that "grouping is like a "structure" or a "record" in conventional programming languages". The below grouping should be what you are looking for:

```
grouping mapping {
   leaf uri {
     type inet:uri;
   }
   list address {
     type inet:IpAddress;
   }
 }
```

Then you can reference such `grouping` by  [the `uses` statement](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7950#section-7.13) like in the following examples:

```
container specific_mapping {
    uses mapping;
}
```

and

```
list my_mapping {
    key "uri";
    uses mapping;
}
```

The following instance documents are compatible with the above:

```
<specific_mapping>
    <uri>some uri</uri>
    <address>address 1</address>
    <address>address 2</address>
</specific_mapping>
```

and

```
<my_mapping>
    <uri>some uri</uri>
    <address>address 1</address>
    <address>address 2</address>
</my_mapping>
<my_mapping>
    <uri>other uri</uri>
    <address>address 3</address>
    <address>address 4</address>
</my_mapping>
```

The `typedef` statement is explained in [this section](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7950#section-7.3) of YANG 1.1. RFC 7950. It is meant to specify a type of a *single* leaf so it cannot be used to create the structure you want to have. When you use `typedef` you define the set of all possible values for that type. This is called *value space*. The [`union` built-in type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7950#section-9.12) that you tried to use is meant to combine value spaces of types listed inside it. `list` is not a type, so it cannot be used there.